# Trouble understanding the word 'qua'

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

I'm Indonesian student study english. I come across word 'qua' in a book ***A Generation of Sociopaths: How the Baby Boomers Betrayed America***.

I try to understand what the word 'Qua' means. I have used a few dictionaries but  I still unable to understand it fully.

Source: Lexico

> Definition: "In the capacity of; as being"
>
> Examples:
>
> Qua musician, he lacks skill, but his playing is lively and enthusiastic. (Does it mean 'As a musician'?)
>
> The work of art qua art can be judged by aesthetic criteria only.

Comment: I'm not sure what I could add.  "Qua" is a rare word meaning "As" or "in the capacity of".  It is a weird Latin borrowing, but the dictionary definition is correct and applies to the examples you have  "As a musician..."  "Art as art"  (and not art as decoration or art as social commentary or art as...)

Comment: What James K said, with emphasis on how very *rare* --and therefore unimportant-- the word is. I see it less than once a year, and I may never have used it in my life.

Comment: Just to expand on "Art *qua* art". "The Eiffel Tower is interesting as architecture, but is not art *qua* art," implying it has some value as extreme architecture, but might not be considered being a work of *art*, as such (i.e., it was not made primarily for the purpose of an art work).

Comment: qua (as)  is used in formal writing quite often as seen in good magazines like The Atlantic Monthly, or The New Yorker and publications like The Times Literary Supplement. It is usually written in italics: art *qua* art. It is often used in reference to ideas and concepts. qua is as but can also be understood as "strictly speaking" *strictu sensu*. [Try and use a better dictionary. Lexico is not that good.] It depends what kinds of conversations one has. I have to admit that I do use it. Does that make me a snob? :)

Comment: I sometimes use "qua" when discussing the ["use-mention distinction"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction). To borrow Wikipedia's example: "'Cheese' is derived from the Old English word ċēse." In this sentence, "cheese" is used not to represent a type of food but instead *qua* a word.

Comment: @Lambie - if you are a snob, then so am I.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The dumbing down of speech is a pity.

Comment: @Lambie - I accidentally used _sine qua non_ in conversation once. Oh dear! In your comment above you mentioned three publications I am very fond of. I still miss the _Listener_.